# In python pandas, How to apply loop to create rows for multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


column_names = [str(x) for x in range(1,4)]

df= pd.DataFrame ( columns = column_names )

new_row = []

for i in range(3):
    new_row.append(i)


df = df.append(new_row , ignore_index = True) 


print(df)
```

---

output:

```
     1    2    3    0
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0
```

---

Is there a way to apply the loop to column 1, column 2, and column 3?

I think it's possible with a simple code, isn't it?

I've been thinking a lot, but I don't know how.

I also tried the .loc() method, but I couldn't apply the loop to the row of columns.

---

This is a supplementary explanation.

'column_names = [str(x) for x in range(1,4)]' creates columns 0 to 3.

A loop is applied to each column.

The "for" loop inserts 0 through 2 into column 1.

Therefore, 0, 1, 2 are input to the row of column 1.

The result I want is below.

[image]

---

Comment: You want to create one row with one value each for each column, or 3 rows with 3 values each for each column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code after all your codes above:

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = new_row
```

Result:

If you run after all your codes:

```
column_names = [str(x) for x in range(1,4)]

df= pd.DataFrame ( columns = column_names )

new_row = []

for i in range(3):
    new_row.append(i)

df = df.append(new_row , ignore_index = True)
```

Then run the code here:

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = new_row
```

You should get:

```
print(df)

   1  2  3  0
0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2  2
```

Comment: It's funny I don't understand the same thing. The variable name is `new_row` so I think the OP want to add only one row.

Comment: @Corralien  Right!  Just guess what OP want.  Don't know right or wrong yet.

Comment: The result is as follows.
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 2, 3]
Index: []

Comment: @yodoro  Did you also run your original code `df = df.append(new_row , ignore_index = True) `   ?   I assumed you already run it.

Comment: @yodoro  If you didn't run that line, the result should still have 3 columns 1, 2, 3 with the values.   What version of Pandas you have ?

Comment: Just deleted "for i in range(3): / new_row.append(i)" -> I did the rest of the code.

Comment: @yodoro  I'm afraid you have to keep the line `"for i in range(3): / new_row.append(i)"`.  It is because this defines the contents of `new_row`.  Without this line, `new_row` will be empty.

Comment: >>> pd.__version__ / '1.1.3'

Comment: @yodoro  Seems no problem with the Pandas version.  Just that you have to keep the line `"for i in range(3): / new_row.append(i)"`

Comment: Your code also prints fine. I'll have to study other people's code and your code. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's weird but you can use `.loc` to do that:

```
df.loc[len(df.index)+1] = new_row
```

```
>>> df
   1  2  3
1  0  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure what you are trying to do - can you rephrase?

```
import pandas as pd

column_names = [str(x) for x in range(1,4)]
df= pd.DataFrame ( columns = column_names )
new_row = []
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    new_row.append(i)
df = df.append(new_row , ignore_index = True)
for i in df:
    df[i] = new_row
print(df)
```

Comment: If you don't know what he means, what are you answering to?

Comment: An error occurs.
line 18, in <module>
     x=df.at[0,i]
indexing.py", line 2080, in __getitem__
     return super().__getitem__(key)
indexing.py", line 2027, in __getitem__
     return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  frame.py", line 3006, in _get_value
     series = self._get_item_cache(col)
generic.py", line 3540, in _get_item_cache
     loc = self.columns.get_loc(item)
base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
     raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0

Comment: Thanks @Aryerez, unfortunately I lack the reputation to be able to comment. I think the above should do what you want.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the name of the column for example:

```
for col in column_names:
    df[col] = new_row
```

Comment: Without deleting the existing 'for' loop,
  The code should be inserted just before print(df).
The output is fine.
thank you.
I'll have to study your code more.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the new row to the next index position in the dataframe using .loc.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

column_names = [str(x) for x in range(1,4)]

df= pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

new_row = []

for i in range(3):
    new_row.append(i)

df.loc[len(df)] = new_row
```

If you have multiple rows to add in a loop,

```
len(df)
```

in the .loc statement will ensure they're always being added to the end.

Comment: The output is like this    1  2  3 / 
0  0  1  2

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve?

And is 1 2 3 / 0 0 1 2 the column headers (1 2 3), then the first index (0) and then the values (0 1 2)?

Comment: The results to be obtained are attached as pictures in the text.
And as you asked, 123 is the columns, 0 0 12 is the first row.